# How to create a custom exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'm trying to create a custom exception based on an error I am getting. This is my code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError, ProfileNotFound
try:
    login_profile = client.get_login_profile(UserName=user_name)
    login_profile = (login_profile['LoginProfile']['UserName'])
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception", e)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Exception An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetLoginProfile operation: Login Profile for User tdunphy cannot be found.
```

I tried adding that error as an exception, but it didn't work:

```
try:
    login_profile = client.get_login_profile(UserName=user_name)
    login_profile = (login_profile['LoginProfile']['UserName'])
except NoSuchEntity:
    print("The login profile does not exist.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception", e)
```

Gives me these errors:

```
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException: An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetLoginProfile operation: Login Profile for User tdunphy cannot be found.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
NameError: name 'NoSuchEntity' is not defined
```

And using this exception instead:

```
except NoSuchEntityException:
```

Gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'NoSuchEntityException' is not defined
```

How can I create an exception for this error that works?

Comment: You don't _create_ an exception [class] for this to work. You want to _find out_ where `botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException` comes from and how to import it.

Comment: You need to use the fully qualified class name `botocore.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException`, or add `NoSuchEntityException` to your `from ... import ...` list.

Comment: Can you import the `NoSuchEntityException` from `botocore.exceptions`?

Comment: No, I get an error when I try to do that: `ImportError: cannot import name 'NoSuchEntityException' from 'botocore.exceptions'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define NoSuchEntityException. Example:

```
class NoSuchEntityException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "No Such Entity Exception."
```

Or maybe NoSuchEntityException is defined in other module that you did not import.

edit:

I think this might be what you are after:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sampleText')
try:
    pass
except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:` worked!

Answer (score 2):

Import the name of this exception in addition to `ClientError` and `ProfileNotFound`:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError, ProfileNotFound, NoSuchEntityException


try:
    login_profile = client.get_login_profile(UserName=user_name)
    login_profile = (login_profile['LoginProfile']['UserName'])
except NoSuchEntityException:
    print("The login profile does not exist.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception", e)
```

Answer (score 0):

`except` will catch a specific `Exception` class. This means that the exception you handle with `except` needs to be defined. The `exceptions` module in `goto` also holds the `NoSuchEntityException` as you noted, so import and use accordingly:

```py
from goto.exceptions import ClientError, ProfileNotFound, NoSuchEntityException

try:
    login_profile = client.get_login_profile(UserName=user_name)
    login_profile = (login_profile['LoginProfile']['UserName'])

except NoSuchEntityException as e:
    print("Profile isn't found!")
    # do something or exit

except Exception as e:
    raise # Don't know what to do yet, so don't handle this
```

If you *must* subclass, you can with the base `Exception` class:

```py
class NoSuchEntitiyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "No such entity"

try:
    #code
except NoSuchEntityException:
    # do something
```

As a note, using `print` in the `except` clause can cause problems as the program will still progress forward:

```py
try:
    raise ValueError("test error")
    x = 5
except ValueError:
    print("Got a value error!")

print(x)
# NameError: x is not defined
```